# Does RStudio have a "read aloud" option for visually-impaired data scientists?

Tags: r, rstudio, accessibility

I am visually impaired, using R with RStudio for several years.
Does RStudio have a read aloud option? I am looking for a similar option as the "read aloud" option in Microsoft Word, that could read the code aloud.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360045612413-RStudio-Screen-Reader-Support).   The take away is that it's in development with screen reader support more advanced with (browser based) RStudio Server than Desktop:  "Due to underlying accessibility issues introduced by components used to build RStudio Desktop, we cannot yet recommend its use via a screen reader except in an experimental fashion. We are actively working with the developer of these components to get these issues addressed, and will be releasing updates with these fixes as soon as we can."

Comment: This would probably better be addressed at RStudio's own support site: https://community.rstudio.com/